# Regex: How to remove English words from sentences using Regex?

Tags: regex, t-sql

I've number of rows in SQLite, each row has one column that contains data like this:

```
prosperکامیاب شدن ، موفق شدن ، رونق یافتن
```

As you can see, the sentence starts with English words, Now I want to remove English words at first of each sentence. Is there any way to do that via T-SQL query(using Regex)?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with T-SQL and the regex it implemetns, but perhaps I can try to point you in the rigth direction after a quick bit of googling. a regex to find any characters that are not in the latin A-z would be something like `[^a-zA-Z]`. It looks like T-SQL Regex does not support start of line matching (`^`), but normally I would match the start of line to start looking for the first word in a line. Not a complete answer, but maybe it will give you a place to start looking

Comment: Maybe look at defining the character set that you want to keep and then match one or more characters not in that set. That way you would also pick up words in French or Kanji or Dingbats, etc. Anyway, the range of characters you want is probably better known than the set of things you don't want.

Comment: English words? You would have to use an English dictionary. Might try to remove Latin 1 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this :) I have made it as a function to call upon

```
create function dbo.RemoveEngChars (@Unicode_string nvarchar(max))
returns nvarchar(max) as
begin
declare @i int = 1;  -- must start from 1, as SubString is 1-based
declare @OriginalString nvarchar(100)   = @Unicode_string collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1256_CS_AS
declare @ModifiedString nvarchar(100) = N'';

while @i <= Len(@OriginalString)
  begin
    if SubString(@OriginalString, @i, 1) not like '[a-Z]'
    begin
      set @ModifiedString = @ModifiedString + SubString(@OriginalString, @i, 1);
    end
    set @i = @i + 1;
  end
return @ModifiedString
end

--To call the function , you can run the following script and pass the Unicode in N' prefix
select dbo.RemoveEngChars(N'prosperکامیاب شدن ، موفق شدن ، رونق یافتن')
```